# I have an alert dialog and using setSingleChoiceItems to set the selected item, but want to display the list from top

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an alert dialog window and using the below code to set the choice item from the list as default. I couldn't find any proper solution in Stackoverflow so adding the question

**CustomDialog class that returns a Dialog to my Activity**

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         ...
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder();
    b.setSingleChoiceItems(Language.names, 5, new OnClickListener() {
       ....
    }

    AlertDialog dialog = b.create();

    return dialog;
 }
```

**In Activity:**

```
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    CustomDialog alert = new CustomDialog();

    // Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    // Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object : Get current language
    // code and set the position
    b.putInt("position", 5); // sending the 5

    // Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object
    alert.setArguments(b);

    // Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window
    alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");
```

Now it displays the particular position which is right, but issue I have is it scrolls the position and keep this position in the top.

Is there a way I can set the list to be displayed starting at position 0 but the selected item is 5. So idea is pass 5 and show 5 selected but it should start the display at 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the index of your selected item in the `setSingleChoiceItems()` call, pass `-1` to indicate that no item is checked, and then manually select the item you want after the `AlertDialog` shows.

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(...);
        ...

        // We can just pass -1 here, since we'll be
        // setting the selected item later anyway

        b.setSingleChoiceItems(Language.names, -1, new OnClickListener() {
                ....
            }
        );

        AlertDialog dialog = b.create();
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Grab the position from the arguments,
        // and set that item as checked

        final int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        final AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
        dialog.getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}
```